# How to generate autobins for all variables of a struct easily

Tags: validation, code-coverage, system-verilog

Say I have the following covergroup and struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    bit [17:0] y;
    logic z;
    // ... assume many more variables
} a2b_req_t;

a2b_req_t a2b_req;

covergroup a2b_req_cg @(a2b_req_event);
    A2B_REQ: coverpoint a2b_req;
endgroup
```

The above is syntactically incorrect, because you cannot have a coverpoint on a struct, but only its member variables. Without creating coverpoints for each member variable, how can I generate autobins for each member variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this other than to explicitly write a coverpoint for each member variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can try vcs lca features, like
vcs -lca -sverilog -ntb_opts echo_cov_gen foo.sv
For more detail, see https://spdocs.synopsys.com/dow_retrieve/latest/vg/VCS/PDFs/VCSLCAFeatures.pdf
Chapter Echo - Automatic Generation of a Coverage Model From
Constraints

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).